# Getting error in react-redux reducer unexpected

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I thought I had safely created a new state and returned with the following code inside my Redux reducer.  Basically, I need to change one record inside my state.data array and return the new state.  My expectation was that since newState is completely new that I was good.

After installing redux-immutable-state-invariant, I'm seeing that I still have a problem (code and error below).

```
    let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
    let newData = [];
    newState.data.map(function(rec){
        if (rec.id === sessionIdToUpdate) {
            rec.interestLevel = newInterestLevel;
            newData.push(rec);
        } else {
            newData.push(rec);
        }
    });
    newState.data = newData;
    return newState;
```

and the error...

```
A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: `sessions.data.0.interestLevel`
```

If I comment out the line

```
rec.interestLevel = newInterestLevel;
```

the error goes away, but then so does the purpose of this reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `Object.assign({}, state)` creates a shallow copy, and `data` and all its `rec` objects are shared with the previous state object. If you assign to one of them, you mutate the old state.

Instead of mutating the `rec`, you can specify the new state declaratively with something like this:

```
const newState = {
  ...state,
  data: state.data.map((rec) => 
    rec.id === sessionIdToUpdate ? {...rec, interestLevel: newInterestLevel} : rec        
  )
};
```

Comment: Thanks @oblosys and also thanks for the demo of returning a value from map sets that value to the record.  I did not realize that (obviously).